# DataFrame constructor not properly called! with JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to read in a json file and covert to a dataframe. But i'm unable to full do so using two different methods.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


for m_file in os.listdir('.'):
    if m_file.startswith('180830') and m_file.endswith('_out.json'):
        input_file2 = open(m_file, 'r')
        output_json = input_file2.read()

        #output_df = pd.read_json(output_json, orient=str) #gives me ValueError: Expected object or value error
        output_df = pd.DataFrame(eval(output_json)) #gives me the contructor error
        print(output_df)
```

Comment: your indentation doesn't look right here for starters.

Comment: Fixed it but that isn't the cause.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `eval()` instead of `json.load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas can read a file path.

Try:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


for m_file in os.listdir('.'):
    if m_file.startswith('180830') and m_file.endswith('_out.json'):
        output_df = pd.DataFrame(m_file) 
        print(output_df)
```